# AddOrUpdate в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Есть метод `AddOrUpdate`, который позволяет немного сократить объем кода.

Можно ли как-нибудь не все подряд обновлять, а лишь часть полей, которые будут перечислены или все-таки придется писать свои методы со своей логикой?

Comment: А зачем вы изменяете несколько полей, а обновить хотите только некоторые? Объясните, какая ваша реальная задача.

Comment: Не знаю, на сколько мой подход верный... Есть у меня модель, которую нужно синхронизировать с БД, на которой нету ORM. Я не стал делать новый тип, а взял в качестве контейнера класс сущности(50% полей совпадает с классом и их мне нужно синхронизировать). Я получаю данные из другой базы в List<Entity> и синхронизирую его со своей бд, где есть ОРМ.

Comment: Понял. Я бы сделал два _различных_ класса, и отобразил `Entity1` на `Entity2` каким-нибудь AutoMapper'ом. Ну или написал бы функцию отображения вручную, в конце-концов.

Answer (score 0):

На EF Core у меня работает вот такой код. возможно и вам подойдет

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;


namespace Rox.Extensions.DB
{
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static void SyncProperty<T>(this T target, T source, IEnumerable<string> properiesName = null)
            where T : class
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);
            var properties = t.GetRuntimeProperties();
            if (properiesName != null) properties = properties.Where(p => properiesName.Contains(p.Name));

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(source, null);
                var valueTarget = prop.GetValue(target, null);

                if (value != null && !value.Equals(valueTarget))
                    prop.SetValue(target, value);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<T> UpdateAsync<T>(this DbContext db, T entity, bool save = true)
            where T : class
        {
            var entry = db.Entry(entity);
            var primaryKey = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey();
            if (primaryKey != null)
            {
                var nameKeys = primaryKey.Properties.Select(p => p.Name);
                var properies = entry.Metadata.GetProperties()?.Where(p => !nameKeys.Contains(p.Name) && !p.IsReadOnlyAfterSave && !p.IsReadOnlyBeforeSave && !p.IsShadowProperty)?.Select(p => p.Name);
                entity.SyncProperty(entity, properies);
            }
            else
            {
                entity.SyncProperty(entity);
            }

            if (save)
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entry.Entity;
        }

        public static async Task<TEntity> AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity, TContext>(this TContext db, TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> key, bool save = true)
            where TContext : DbContext, IDisposable
            where TEntity : class
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

            var dbEntity = await db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(key);
            if (dbEntity != null)
            {
                dbEntity = await db.UpdateAsync(dbEntity, save: false);
            }
            else
            {
                dbEntity = db.Add(entity).Entity;
            }

            if (save)
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return dbEntity;
        }
    }
}
```